# ¿Cómo guardar automáticamente un nuevo documento html desde php?

Tags: php

Tengo una archivo php que genera una firma de correo y que pide ciertos datos como el nombre, puesto por ejemplo, una vez rellenado) y los almacena en distintas variables para insertarlos en una plantilla y poder un archivo html.

El caso es que no sé como hacer, para que una vez recoja los datos, el fichero php, cree un documento html nuevo en una carpeta de mi direcctorio con esos datos automaticamente.
el codigo para descargarlo es el siguiente:

```
 if (!empty($_REQUEST['download'])) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=efirma.html');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar fopen, fwrite. Ejemplo:

```
if(! ($fp = fopen("fichero.html", "w"))
     die('Error al crear fichero.html')

if(!fwrite($fp, $contenido))
     die('Error al escribir en fichero.html');

fclose($fp);
```

Lee esto:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Igual hay otra forma con get_contents y no te evitas dos líneas

Answer (score -1):

lo logre con:`file_put_contents('firmas/datos.html', $contenido);` pero me gustaria saber si es posible que guarde el archivo con el texto insertado en el input?

Comment: deberias de plantiar una pregunta nueva por que tu respuesta es igual a una pregunta por la razon de preguntar por el input que no esta en tu pregunta original